# Package com.google.gwt.logging.Logging does not seem to be found

Tags: java, logging, gwt

I am trying to add logging in a GWT project. I am following this documentation: http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideLogging.html#Super_Simple_Recipe_for_Adding_Logging

The directory tree is as follow:

```
my-project
|-src
  |-main
    |-java
      |-portal
        |-Portal.gwt.xml
        |-client
          |-...
            |-MyClass.java
```

In `Portal.gwt.xml`, I added the following:

```
<inherits name="com.google.gwt.logging.Logging"/>
```

In `MyClass` constructor, I added the following lines:

```
Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("NameOfYourLogger");
logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "this message should get logged");
```

I also added this line at the top:

```
import com.google.gwt.logging.Logging;
```

However, when I try to compile my project, I get the following errors:

```
  [ERROR] Line 64: Logger cannot be resolved to a type
  [ERROR] Line 64: Logger cannot be resolved
  [ERROR] Line 65: Level cannot be resolved to a variable
```

I also opened the project in my IDE (IntelliJ IDEA), the new package does not seem to be found (I got the message `Cannot resolve symbol "Logging"` when hovering over the corresponding line).

What could be the cause of this issue?

Comment: did you try `import com.google.gwt.logging.*`

Comment: Is the jar part of your dependencies.

Comment: `java.util.logging` is now a part of [GWT JRE](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/RefJreEmulation.html#Package_java_util_logging). Try using that instead of `com.google.gwt.logging.Logging`. You don't need to inherit any new module.

Comment: I ended up using `GWT.log`, which produces the desired effect.